# trig event when created or deleted

Tags: c#, delegates, event-handling

I wish to trig event when class instance is created (or deleted), but my the class itself.
It seems impossible (because no other class instance can simultaneously create object and add handler on the event of created class). Is there an other way ?

```
public class MyClass {
public delegate void delegate_MyClassCreated( MyClass me);
public delegate_MyClassCreated event_MyClassCreated;

public delegate void delegate_MyClassDeleted( MyClass me);
public delegate_MyClassDeleted event_MyClassDeleted;

public MyClass() {

    //... some initialisations here...

    try {
        event_MyClassCreated( this);
        }
    catch {}
    }

~ MyClass() {
    try {
        event_MyClassDeleted( this);
        }
    catch {}
    }
}

//...
// in other class
((MyClass)new MyClass()).event_MyClassCreated += callback_MyClassCreated;
// ...

void callback_MyClassCreated( MyClass me) {
    // action on me
    }
```

Comment: In first place **why**? May be there is a better way to achieve If you can say why! BTW You can fire `static` event which makes it possible :)

Comment: Also note that destructors are nasty. they extend the life of objects. I don't see any good reason to have a `finalizer`. Finalized doesn't mean that object went away from memory, object can live further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use *static* events? Something like that:

```
  public class MyClass {
    ...
    // static event doesn't need any instance and so 
    // could be called within constructor
    public static event EventHandler MyClassCreated;

    public MyClass() {
      ...

      if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(null, MyClassCreated))
        MyClassCreated(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    } 
  }
```

...

```
  // Assigning callback for the event (no MyClass instance required)
  MyClass.MyClassCreated += callback_MyClassCreated;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an IoC container such as [Autofac](http://autofac.org/) :-)

I am unsure about Unity, but at least Autofac has so-called Activation Events, where you may handle the creation of an instance either in a general manner or type-specific.
Have a look at this [blog post](http://xharze.blogspot.com/2010/07/autofac-part-3-module-registration-and.html).

If you wish to not use e.g. Autofac, you are probably left with a DIY implementation. - This could be implementing factories for your classes, which as part of the instantiation process fires an event.

Quick'n'Dirty DIY Example using static events:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myCreatingEventHandler = new EventHandler((sender, eventArgs) => Console.WriteLine("Creating"));
            var myCreatingEventHandler2 = new EventHandler((sender, eventArgs) => Console.WriteLine("Creating2"));
            var myDisposingEventHandler = new EventHandler((sender, eventArgs) => Console.WriteLine("Disposing"));
            var myDisposingEventHandler2 = new EventHandler((sender, eventArgs) => Console.WriteLine("Disposing2"));

            MyClass.Creating += myCreatingEventHandler;
            MyClass.Disposing += myDisposingEventHandler;
            using (var test = new MyClass())
            {
                // Prints "Creating" and "Disposing".
            }

            Console.WriteLine();

            MyClass.Creating += myCreatingEventHandler2;
            MyClass.Disposing += myDisposingEventHandler2;
            using (var test = new MyClass())
            {
                // Prints "Creating", "Creating2", "Disposing" and "Disposing2".
            }

            Console.WriteLine();

            MyClass.Creating -= myCreatingEventHandler;
            MyClass.Disposing -= myDisposingEventHandler;
            using (var test = new MyClass()) {
                // Prints "Creating2" and "Disposing2".
            }

            Console.WriteLine();

            MyClass.Creating -= myCreatingEventHandler2;
            MyClass.Disposing -= myDisposingEventHandler2;
            using (var test = new MyClass())
            {
                // Prints nothing (removed subscriptions to avoid "memory leak".
            }

            // You may choose call such a method to ensure that ALL handlers are removed from the invocation list.
            MyClass.RemoveSubscriptions();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    internal class MyClass : IDisposable
    {
        public static event EventHandler Creating;

        private static void OnCreating()
        {
            EventHandler handler = Creating;
            if (handler != null) handler(null, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        public static event EventHandler Disposing;

        private static void OnDisposing()
        {
            EventHandler handler = Disposing;
            if (handler != null) handler(null, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        public MyClass()
        {
            OnCreating();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            OnDisposing();
        }

        public static void RemoveSubscriptions()
        {
            // Setting the events to null can only be done from within the class. From the outside only += and -= are allowed.
            Creating = null;
            Disposing = null;
        }
    }
}
```

However, I do not recommend going with the static event approach. Why? - Because you have to be *very* careful when using static events. If you do not remove the handlers explicitly, you will have the managed equivalent to a memory leak. It may produce unpredictable behavior. You don't want that ;-)

My recommendation as the safest choice would be going with e.g. **Autofac** and gain a several other goodies in the process ;-)
However, it does not handle when the instance is disposed. - Any reason you wish to listen for that event?